# svn CruiseControlException - FileName.svn-base': The system cannot find the file specified.

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net, ankhsvn, cruisecontrol

Some how I corrupted my svn.

The following is what I did:

1. Had Checked in file "RegularUser.master".
2. I deleted the file.
3. Realized I needed it and recreated it with the same name.
4. Checked it in.

   - Received an error:  `ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: Failed to add file 'E:\CCNetBuild\MyDirectory\trunk\...\...\RegularUser.master': an unversioned file of the same name already exists`
5. Deleted the file.
6. Checked it in.

   - Received a svn checksum error.
7. Reverted the code to last successful build.
8. Checked it in.

   - Received the following error:

> ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: In directory 'MyDirectory'
>   svn: Can't open file 'E:\CCNetBuild\MyDirectory\trunk.......svn\tmp\text-base\RegularUser.master.svn-base': The system cannot find the file specified.
>   . Process command: C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe update E:\CCNetBuild\MyDirectory --revision 53 --username srvmoppwbuild --password ******** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive
>   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
>   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.UpdateSource(IIntegrationResult result)
>   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
>   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
>   
>   
>   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things to fix this error. I deleted **RegularUser.master** and added **RegularUser.Master**. Tried to delete both and checking them in.

The only thing that worked was when I went into the actual build server and deleted both files: RegularUser.master and RegularUser.Master. The issue stemmed from the fact that svn supports different casing for files and treats them as two separate files while a windows OS only treats casing as the same.

**General Advice: Never name the same file in different casing and check it in. It can mess up your svn repository.**

Answer (score 0):

> Source control operation failed: svn: Failed to add file `E:\CCNetBuild\MyDirectory\trunk\..\..\RegularUser.master`: an unversioned file of the same name already exists

The error is very simple. You have a file that's in your CruiseControl's Subversion working directory called `E:\CCNetBuild\RegularUser.master`. This file previously was not in your Subversion repository, but now is part of Subversion. When CruiseControl attempts to checkout this file, it finds that unversioned file currently sitting there. The warning is to delete this file.